# C++ Classes what is ROMable and what is not ROMable? (STM32)

Tags: c++, oop, compilation, embedded, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class A
{
    public:
        static const int member_1 = 5;
        static const unsigned char member_2[9] = "member_2";
        static const string member_3 = "member_3";

        static const int method_1(int parameter_1);
        static int method_2(int parameter_1);

}
```

**For the STM32 platform, what is ROMable in this class?**

For standard layout, trivial or POD types you can run is_standard_layout, is_trivial or is_pod test if the object meets the type. Is there any such method to check if a class is ROMable?

In the official documentation [Technical Report on C++ Performance Section 7.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf) it is unclear what is the case for classes in terms of ROMability. My interpretation is that each member/method of a class would be evaluated separately and if it has the const keyword then it will be ROMable and if not then it is vague and totally up to the compiler.

Comment: The linked documentation is quite clear on the requirements for "ROMability", and provides a laundry-list of ROMable objects. But even without that technical specification, it is quite obvious what things are ROMable and which things are not. All you really have to understand is how objects work in C++. Even without going through the list, it's quite obvious that the first two are, the third one may or may not, it might be, with a really good C++ compiler, and the two functions are not in scope, at all.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  What do you mean by "the two functions are not in scope"?  Also i'm not too familiar with how the internals of how objects work in C++, to be honest not sure what that even means, do you mean how the compiler compiles objects? The terminology is unfamiliar in the document, I always thought of objects as classes alone. But the document refers to all variables int, char, double as objects. This among other things made that documentation unclear.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I have edited the answer to include the platform.

Comment: When in doubt, open the linker script, find `.heap` and nuke it. When you later on get strange linker errors about memory segments not being available, you'll know that you've messed up, by using std::vector or some other PC programming construct.

Comment: Each compiler system has tools that show in which section each object is placed. Read the documentation and use the tools. You will learn from their output.

Comment: Without seeing what these functions do, one cannot conclude with 100% certainty that they're ROMmable. They probably are, but can't commit to that without a complete inspection and analysis. And when dealing with niche applications, like embedded systems, you really need to understand how compiled C++ code works, and how "objects work". How constructors, and virtual inheritance works. The nuts and the bolts of it. Otherwise this is like trying to use a car to go somewhere without a complete grasp on what those pedals on the floor are, and what's this round thing in front of me is all about.